# Kubernetes Service Not Reachable Via NodePort

Tags: kubernetes, centos, weave, kubernetes-nodeport

I have deployed my K8s cluster in **CentOS** which consists of 1 Master and 2 Nodes. I am exposing my services to the external world using NodePort. My service is -

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: atcapi
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: atcapi
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: atcapi-http
    port: 57124
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32510
    protocol: TCP
...
```

I am able to connect to the service using my worker node ip and NodePort but not using Master Node IP and NodePort.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to access service with **Master IP**.

i think it's expected only because **master** for managing the **cluster** not should be used for exposing the services.

You can setup the **Ingress** or **service mesh** to expose the service or Use **Node port** service with **worker node IP**.

Still, you are looking for that check your **IP table & Firewall** rules those might could be blocking your traffic.

Comment: Yes, we should do it but its dev environment and we wanted to have single IP to access all services. There is no firewall and checked IP table as well. It was working earlier but infra team made some changes and those changes are reverted but cluster issue did not get resolved.